# Django, users in group sorted

Tags: django

I want to show the users of each group of my Django app.

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <h2>{{ group }}</h2>
    {% for user in group.user_set.all %}
        <div>
            {{ user }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works great, but for this specific template, I'd like the users to be sorted by their date_joined attribute.

How could I achieve that? I suspect that it could be done using a custom filter but I am not really sure if it is the right way or if there is a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try serializers

serializer.py

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    class UserSerializerserializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username')
            order_by = ('date_joined')

    class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        users = UserSerializerserializers(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Group
            fields = ('name', 'users')


    >  groups = Group.objects.all() 
    >  required_result = GroupSerializer(groups,many=True)
    >  required_result.data # will give you a json
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by using a custom filter.

```
@register.filter_function
def order_by(queryset, args):
    args = [x.strip() for x in args.split(',')]
    return queryset.order_by(*args)
```

Then, in my template I just use that filter and it works like a charm.

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <h2>{{ group }}</h2>
    {% for user in group.user_set.all|order_by:"date_joined" %}
        <div>
            {{ user }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```